# How to make spatie/permissions checks in livewire component?

Tags: laravel-livewire

In Laravel 8 / livewire 2.5 I use       spatie/laravel-permission 5 and for CRUD operations I make checks in components like

```
public function edit()
{
    $loggedUser = Auth::user();

    if ( $loggedUser->can(PERMISSION_EDIT_HOSTEL) ) {
        return view('livewire.error-msg', [
    ...
```

and I need to make such checks in any method of my component.
Looking at Lifecycle Hooks I wonder if there is a way to keep all checks in one place ?
How can I implement it ?

**UPDATED BLOCK #1:**

I try to use booted method, I see that is has 1 parameter like :

```
Livewire\Request Object
(
    [fingerprint] => Array
        (
            [id] => N88CNnpmNSd1xzBTuGQc
            [name] => admin.crud-items
            [locale] => en
            [path] => admin/items
            [method] => GET
        )

    [updates] => Array
        (
        )

    [memo] => Array
        (
        )
```

when I show listing(render method) and when I call "edit" method :

```
 Livewire\Request Object
        (
            [fingerprint] => Array
                (
                    [id] => N88CNnpmNSd1xzBTuGQc
                    [name] => admin.crud-items
                    [locale] => en
                    [path] => admin/items
                    [method] => GET
                )

            [updates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => callMethod
                            [payload] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => ki8a
                                    [method] => edit
                                    [params] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 44
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )
...
```

It permits me to make checks I need, but I doubt to use  booted method parameter, which is not described in docs.
Or there is some official docs on it ? Is it good way/safe to use this way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please look at UPDATED BLOCK #1

Comment: were you able to solve it? I also need it

Comment: No, checking parameters in  booted method it seems not good for all cases, so I added code in top of control's of any method